# Crystal reports, trying to use: startswith and looking for 2 values

Tags: sql, ms-access, crystal-reports

I am new with Crystal Reporting. I need to search the records and find all records that start with the letter "P" and "W"

Would I say something like this? `{MNBDD.BD_ORD} startswith ["W", "P"]`
Or something like, `{MNBDD.BD_ORD} startswith ["W" OR "P"]`
Or something like, `{MNBDD.BD_ORD} startswith ["W" AND "P"]`

What I am wanting to do it just return the records with P and W in the front. but, I don't want to leave any out.

Comment: try the syntax {MNBDD.BD_ORD} like "W%" OR {MNBDD.BD_ORD} like "P%"

Answer (score 4):

you can try like this in crystal reports:

```
{MNBDD.BD_ORD} like "P*" and 
{MNBDD.BD_ORD} like "W*"
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume your table name is MNBDD and BD_ORD is the column which should start with either 'P' or 'W'. Then this query should work for you.

```
select * from MNBDD 
where MNBDD.BD_ORD like 'W%' 
or MNBDD.BD_ORD like 'P%';
```

`like` compares the column values with the specified string pattern where '%' signifies wildcard string. This will fetch all records that start with either 'P' or 'W' without leaving out any records.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested under Crystal Reports 2013 and it looks like your first option works:

> {MNBDD.BD_ORD} **startswith** ["P", "W"]

The keyword is **startswith** in Crystal Reports which functions as "W*" or "P*", * being a wildcard.